# Windows 10 dual monitor - on one of the resolutions is locked at 800x600

Tags: window, 4k-resolution

I have two UHD monitors attached to a laptop via adaptors. one of them is showing at native resolution of 3840 x 2160. The other is at 800x600 and cannot be changed (grayed out and cannot be clocked to change.)
I've looked at other posts and already updated the graphic card drivers and installed windows updates after going into Safe mode. I've also changed HDMI cables.
What else can I do to unlock the 800x600 resolution?

My setting is:
two Samsung Samsung  UJ59
laptop: yoga920
OS Window 10 Pro
Graphic card: Intel UHD Graphics 620
monitor adaptor / dock

Comment: It could be the adaptor? Is it a single adaptor for both monitors?

Comment: it is a single adaptor for both monitors but I've actually changed the adaptor before, and its the same thing

Answer (score 0):

I came across a similar situation on an Dell Latitude 3440 with Intel graphics using a Dell USB C dock to connect 2x 1080p Display port monitors.

Screen resolution would be ok until laptop lid was closed and laptop went to sleep. One monitor would stay at 1080p resolution and the other monitor would be greyed out at 800x600 resolution. Workaround for me was to repower the USB C dock and both monitors reverted to 1080p native resolution.

Problem seemed to occur after amending Windows 10 setting System > Power & sleep > Additional power settings > When closing the lid from 'Sleep' to 'Do Nothing'. You can try toggling this setting as well.